# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Expatriates Stack Exchange](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How far back does USA care where you lived, when applying for citizenship based on 3+ years of marriage](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5616/how-far-back-does-usa-care-where-you-lived-when-applying-for-citizenship-based)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Entering the UK with a valid EEA Family Permit about to expire](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5628/entering-the-uk-with-a-valid-eea-family-permit-about-to-expire)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is Dual Residency between the EU & UK Possible with Permanent Residency Visa (ILR)?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5567/is-dual-residency-between-the-eu-uk-possible-with-permanent-residency-visa-il)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can I pass my UK driver's licence with my EU (French) passport?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5585/can-i-pass-my-uk-drivers-licence-with-my-eu-french-passport)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can I invite my parents from inside another EU country?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5562/can-i-invite-my-parents-from-inside-another-eu-country)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does foreign earned, excluded income count as gross income for the filing requirement?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/does-foreign-earned-excluded-income-count-as-gross-income-for-the-filing-requir)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Indian Citizen Planning to marry Polish Citizen](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5556/indian-citizen-planning-to-marry-polish-citizen)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Working for a US-Based Company Remotely in the Netherlands](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5548/working-for-a-us-based-company-remotely-in-the-netherlands)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Returning to my US address, do I get a special enrollment period to sign up for health insurance?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5658/returning-to-my-us-address-do-i-get-a-special-enrollment-period-to-sign-up-for)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5541/how-to-prepare-for-life-in-the-uk-test-in-2015

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 6)

---